# How to read specific columns from CSV file?

Tags: java, csv

I have one csv file which contains 5 fields(columns). Out of 5 columns I want to read second and fourth only which are required for further processing.
Right now I am using readAll() method of opencsv api to read.
By using this method I have to process all columns to get second and fourth column values.

Is there any way to read required column's values i.e. read second and fourth value from csv file?

Is it right approach or should I use any other?

Comment: Even when you have to read all 5 fields where is the problem to discard the fields you won't need ?

Comment: @PeterMmm I want to know whether there is any alternative way to read csv file by header-name. if I specify header, only data under that header should be read..

Comment: The only reasonable way I could think of needs structured (csv-) file. I.e. each field in the file has a known fixed size. If you have fields of arbitrary length you could start to make a guessed search based on a likelihood. Enjoy the implementation. I would rather suggest to import the csv into a DBS.

Comment: are you bound to use open csv api?

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue which is what it looks like from your question I would recommend to implements your own parser. opencsv does not provide such a feature. Probabably because the performance win won't be that big.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

In order to determine which column has which index, a csv-parser has to process the whole line or at least up to the last column you what to have (the fourth one in your case). Even if your data was of fixed length, you still would have to read the whole line so that you know the boundaries of your substrings.

If memory usage is an issue, then using [CSVReader#readAll()](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html#readAll%28%29) is not the best choice. In this case I would suggest using [CSVReader#iterator()](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html#iterator%28%29) instead and access your columns by index of the returner array, e.g. `myCsvRow[1]` and `myCsvRow[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Commons CSV you can iterate over the csv elements and read the specific column using the column label.

Note: (Common CSV is the unification of openCsv and others csv parsers).
       http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

For reading a specific column you can convert each csvRecord to a Map and get its value as follows:

```
List<CSVRecord> aCSVList == aCSVParser.getRecords();
...
for (CSVRecord aCSVRecord : aCSVList)
{
   ...
    Map<String, String> aCurrentMap = aCSVRecord.toMap();
    aCurrentMap.get("ColumnLabel");
}
```